# Black screen at centre of launch screen iOS

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, launch-screen, ios9.2

I placed one launch screen xib in my application it has logo in centre. its working pertly in all devices except iPod.In iPod When i switching between Facebook(for authentication) and application i am seeing a blank screen at the middle of the screen.

[image]

I tried to add 1x, 2x, 3x images and replaced with different icons but no luck, Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using autolayout on your launch screen xib.. ??

Comment: yes, i am using auto layouts.

Comment: Check your constraints then. There might be issues in your autolayout.

Comment: Yes, UIImageView placed centre of the screen and constrains are centre horizontal, centre vertical, fixed height and width thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. It is a bug in Xcode because some how it is caching the launch images. Do the following and it will fix this:

- Reset your iPOD
- Create ipa file of your project
- Push it to your iPOD using iTunes.

I am pretty sure if you are confident about the images you have and your constraints, this will work.